# MYSQL: Select records based on the time intervals

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains records with datetime column. Records will be inserted into that table for every 3/5/8(dynamic) seconds.

Need: I have to show only one record per day. Here I have one condition that is the records should be inserted between 10.00 to 11.00 AM.

So I like to use that condition in where clause and use max to get the record. But I could not.
Please advice.

Comment: @suresh: select *, max(datetime_column) from table where 1 group by date(datetime_column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like below:

```
select * from tblName where HOUR(datetime_column) between 10 AND 11 group by DAY(datetime_column)
```